# Here API - browser decode - api function not working

Tags: here-api

```
http://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=Ca548bnNQGuB45wgmgrU&app_code=WTve4O4ccq_5ErqHb7MQfoiAJP4hLw9UmIeNvjc8s4M&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&prox=<.....> request failed
```

On using the Here API with valid API key and codes, it yields an error as above.   It wants to use the reverse geocode API over https, but is being loaded over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this request which results in success response.

> Request using App_id and App_code

```
https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842%2C-87.6388%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=9&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ
```

> Request with Api_Key

```
https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8842%2C-87.6388%2C250&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&gen=9&apiKey={}
```

These request using **Https** instead of Http.

for more details you can check this link-
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode